# How to JOIN (literaly) two/more ContentProviders in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have a `ContentProvider` with a **DataBase** having two columns named **`"_id"`** and **`"_name"`**. First, i am copying the **id** and **name** from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`. Then i need to change the data in my `ContentProvider`. Then i need to access **`id`** and **`name`** again from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` but on the basis of those **`id`** (s) which are now in my `**ContentProvider**`.

I know how to use `Join` in two tables. But don't know how can i do this using ContentProviders.

Comment: I would query both ContentProviders and use a CursorJoiner.

Comment: @njzk2, thnx..., let me read about `CursorJoiner` coz i have heard this term for the first time.

Comment: @njzk2 , is it only applicable on two cursors with their single coulmns???

Comment: No, why would you say that? You only need to pass the names of the columns to compare, the CursorJoiner does not worry about the other columns. (as you then need to query to original cursors in the iteration on the results.)

Comment: Can u refer me any link or tutorial...m not completely getting it.

Comment: you basically create 2 cursors from your content providers, then create a CursorJoiner from that, then iterate on it, testing is the `result` object is left, right, or both. There is nothing to it.

Comment: In my first Cursor, i have **id**, the second cursor have suppose **names** & **phone_numbers** and the **id**. I need to show names and numbers in a list, but only those whose id match the id of my cursor.

Comment: then the result you are interested in is `BOTH`.

Comment: Thnx @njzk2, its working (filtering) but not exactly the same i wanted, may be my implementation may have some issues. But the Answer of this question is exactly fulfilled. Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do that:

```
Cursor locals = // Get from my local ContentProvider
Cursor distant = // Get from distant phone ContentProvider
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(locals, new String[] {"_id"}, distant, new String[] {"_id"});
for (CursorJointer.Result joinerResult : joiner) {
    switch (joinerResult) {
    case BOTH:
        String name = distant.getString(distant.getColumnIndex("name"));
        names.add(name);
        break;
    }
}
```

`names` contain your list of names.

Comment: Yes...It worked...Thnx alot. :D, i was missing a key point, that both of the columns must be sorted in the same manner. That's why i was getting less filtration.

Comment: Hello @njzk2, can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863038/avoid-swiperefresh-while-fastscrolling-in-android plz, i m stuck in the middle of app